# Reducing colors in a PNG image is making the file size bigger

Tags: graphics, colors, png, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I am using ImageMagick to programmatically reduce the size of a PNG image by reducing the colors in the image. I get the images unique-colors and divide this by 2. Then I assign this value to the -colors option as follows:

variable = unique-colors / 2

convert image.png -colors variable -depth 8

I thought this would substantially reduce the size of the image but instead it increases the images size on disk. Can anyone shed any light on this.

Thanks.

EDIT: Turns out the problem was dithering. Dithering helps your reduced color images look more like the originals but adds to the image size. To remove dithering in ImageMagick add +dither to your command.
Example

convert CandyBar.png +dither -colors 300 -depth 8 smallerCandyBar.png

Comment: It would help if you could give links to two sample png files for us to review. That said, my first guess would be that the latter file is generated without any compression done. Remember that the PNG format supports several compression levels.

Comment: I use the identify function to see what compression is done, both images use the same compression (Zip). Compression levels are an issue for me because even with quality at 90 (the max compression for ImagicMagick PNG's) it creates a much larger file. For this reason I don't use the quality option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagemagick probably uses some dithering algorithm to make image appear as though it has original amount of colors. This increases image data "randomness" (single pixels are recolored at some places to blend into other colors) and this image data no longer packs as well. Research further into how the `convert` command does the dithering. You can also see this effect by adding second image as a layer in gimp/equivalent program and tuning transparency.

Comment: Crap, crap, crap, crap, your completely right. I had no idea dithering added that many bytes to an image; it all makes sense now. I wasted so much time trying to figure this out. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [pngquant](http://pngquant.org) for this.

You don't need to guess number of colors, it has actual `--quality` setting:

```
pngquant --verbose --quality=70 image.png
```

The above will automatically choose number of colors needed to match given quality in the same scale as JPEG quality (100 = perfect, 70 = OK, 20 = awful).

`pngquant` has substantially better quantization algorithm, and the better the quantization the better quality/filesize ratio.

And `pngquant` doesn't dither areas that look good without dithering, and this avoids adding unnecessary noise/randomness to the file.

Answer (score 0):

The "new" PNG's compression is not as good as the one of the original.

Comment: Sorry but I don't fully understand. How could an image compression algorithm be so good that it produces a smaller sized image even when 70% of the colors are removed for the ImagicMagick compressor.